# React: My App reloads after I click the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the code of the component that I have written in my application. In this component, I am rendering a form that also has a table which is dynamically generated. The problem is that when I click on the remove button to delete the entry of a table in the form, my app reloads that is not the desired behaviour that I want.

```
import {ChangeEvent, useState} from 'react';
import { AssetData } from '../../models/asset.model';
 
export default function  CreateAsset()  {
    const  [assetData, setAssetData] =  useState<AssetData>({assetId: "", metaData: [
        {"key": "", "value": ""}]});

    const handleChange = (event: { target: { name: any; value: any; }; }) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setAssetData((prevAssetData) => ({ ...prevAssetData, [name]: value }));
        console.log(assetData);
    };

    const updateMetaData = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, idx: number) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setAssetData((prevAssetData) => {
            const newAssetData = { ...prevAssetData, metaData: [...prevAssetData.metaData  ] }
            const updatedMetaDataEntry =  { ...newAssetData.metaData[idx], [name]: value }
            newAssetData.metaData[idx] = updatedMetaDataEntry
            return newAssetData;
        });
    };

    const handleAddMetaData = () => {
        setAssetData((prevAssetData) => {
            const newAssetData = { ...prevAssetData, metaData: [...prevAssetData.metaData, {"key": "", "value": ""}] }
            return newAssetData;
        });
    };

    const handleRemoveMetaData = (idx: number) => {
        setAssetData((prevAssetData) => {
            const newAssetData = { ...prevAssetData, metaData: [...prevAssetData.metaData  ] }
            newAssetData.metaData.splice(idx, 1)
            return newAssetData;
        });
        
      };

return  (
<form>
    <label htmlFor="assetId">Asset ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="assetId" name="assetId" value={assetData.assetId} onChange={handleChange}/>
    <br></br>
    <label >MetaData:</label>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {assetData.metaData.map((item, idx) => (
                <tr key={idx}>
                    <td><input type="text" name="key" value={item.key} onChange={(e) => updateMetaData(e, idx)}/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="value" value={item.value} onChange={(e) => updateMetaData(e, idx)}/></td>
                    {assetData.metaData.length !== 1 && <td><button onClick={(e) => 
                        {handleRemoveMetaData(idx)}}>Remove</button></td>}
                    {assetData.metaData.length - 1 === idx && <td><button onClick={handleAddMetaData}>Add</button></td>}
                </tr>

            ))}
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
</form>
)};
```

When I should click on the  `Remove` button, only that table row should be deleted but in my case the entire component reloads. I have noticed one more thing. In the onClick callback attached to the Remove button, if I add `e.preventDefault()` statement, my code works as expected and only that table row is deleted. Can anyone guide me what is the reason of the strange behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

> In the onClick callback attached to the Remove button, if I add `e.preventDefault()` statement, my code works as expected and only that table row is deleted.

That's one way to solve the problem, yes.  What you're experiencing is not *strange* behavior, it's *default* behavior.

Unless otherwise specified, the default `type` for a `<button>` element [is `submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).  And the `type` is not specified in your `<button>` elements.  So they're `submit` buttons.

Additionally, a `<form>` with no explicit `action` will submit to the current URL.

Put these together and what you have are buttons which submit your form, doing nothing more than reloading the current page.

Other options to change this behavior include:

- Add `type="button"` to the buttons
- Remove the `<form>` element entirely if you're not planning to use it for anything

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just a small question. I was curious if the default type of every button is submit, why I did not get this error for the Add button that I am using to add rows dynamically in the table. I observed this strange behaviour only for Remove button.

Comment: @UsmanSajid: Good question, and at the moment my only guess is that there's a mistake somewhere in the debugging observations.  If it turns out that what I suggest here isn't what's happening, would you be able to create a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: no my problem solves after changing the type of Remove button as you have mentioned so what you suggested was happening in my case with the Remove button but I was curious why the same thing is not happening to the Add button